# How to see the shader preview?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

In shader editor, how can I see the preview of the shader or any nodes without its being applied to objects? something like 'viewer' node in compositing editor. Right now if I have a lot of 'image texture' nodes in the shader editor, I can't really tell what it is until I connect to the shader network or I have to zoom into the node and check the file path then view it in an image editor? this is really slow. when I select the image texture node, should be a preview in the side panel or anywhere else to see the thumbnail. Any tips? is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Have you enabled the Node Wrangler Add-on? It is in the built-in set, in User Preferences.

Comment: yes, i can have the viewer node (wrangler) , but still it has to be applied to 3d object in the scene right ? can i throw that viewer output to the image editor ?

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+Left Click will create a Node Wrangle Viewer node that is used in the Preview and the Render View. Does that work for you?

Comment: it will create a viewer node but not showing up in render view. i can only see it in 3d viewport.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are asking for <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd>.

Click the final shader, whatever feeds Material Output, to go back to normal.